# null argument java null pointer

Tags: java, arguments, null-pointer

this is my code and I don't know why    "one == null" and "two == null"    are always False and I can't send any Null argument to my method!
please help me

```
public class RepeatInString {
    public int StringInString(String one, String two) {
        if (one.equals("") || two.equals("") || one == null || two == null){
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            char[] oneChar = one.toCharArray();
            char[] twoChar = two.toCharArray();
            int repeatCounter = 0;
            int matchChars = 0;
            for (int i=0 ; i < (one.length()-two.length()+1) ;i++ ){
                matchChars = 0;
                for (int j=0; j<two.length() ;j++) {
                    if (oneChar[i + j] == twoChar[j])
                        matchChars += 1;
                    else
                        break;
                }
                if (matchChars == two.length())
                    repeatCounter += 1;
            }
            return repeatCounter;
        }
    }
```

Comment: string has `isEmpty()` by the way

Comment: There is no point checking if `one==null` after you already called  `one.equals("")` because the attempted method call would have thrown an exception. If you're going to check if things are null, check that first.

Comment: @frozen I always forget that one myself!

Comment: @khelwood zero-length and null are the same?

Comment: can you please include the code that calls your method?

Comment: How do we reproduce your problem?

Comment: @nicomp No, not the same at all

Comment: @khelwood I see the remainder of your comment now. Good catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'dot' is the 'dereference' operator. It means: Take the thingie on the left of the dot, follow the reference, and on the object you find there, do this operation.

Hence, if you write `x.foo()` and `x` is null, you get a `NullPointerException`.

The expression `a || b || c` is resolved left-to-right. First `a` is calculated. If it's true, evaluation ends, the result is already clear. If it is false, then `b` is resolved, and so on and so forth.

So, let's say `one` is null.

First, `one.equals("")` is evaluated (note, you should use `one.isEmpty()`, that's more idiomatic). `one` is null, so, this evaluation results in a thrown `NullPointerException`, and execution ends then and there.

You presumably want `if (one == null || two == null || one.equals("") || two.equals("")) {`.

Except, **you don't want that either**.

null isn't a standin for 'empty'. null is best taken as meaning: Unknown or no value.

So, if I ask you: is 'this unknown value in this other unknown value', the only possible answer is: "I don't know".

If you answer that question with either `true` or `false`, you're lying, or at least guessing. Don't do that. It is perfectly sensible in this scenario to **throw a nullpointerexception** if null is provided.

Sometimes you read input from external systems and it is perfectly acceptable to explicitly choose to treat null input as empty strings or some other sentinel value. If that's the case, do that, explicitly, right there, on the system border.

Comment: thanks a lot my friend it worked and now I have amazing feel

Answer (score 0):

If you pass null argument, you will get NullPointerException because you are doing one.equals(""). Anything null. will throw NullPointerException. You are better with:

```
 if (one == null || two == null || one.equals("") || two.equals("")){
```

if first condition is true, rest of the conditions will be ignored.

Comment: yes it worked thank you